# If $T\times T$ is ergodic, then so is $T\times T\times T$

Tags: ergodic-theory

Given a measure preserving system $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu, T)$, show that $T \times T$ is ergodic with
respect to $\mu\times \mu$ if and only if $T \times T \times T$ is ergodic with respect to $\mu\times \mu\times \mu$.

I have already shown that the reverse implication holds. For "$\Rightarrow$", maybe it suffices to show that for all $A\times B\times C\in \mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{F}$ there is  a set of full measure, $M$ say, such that all $(a,b,c)\in M$ have an $n\in\mathbb{N}: (T^{3})^n(a,b,c)\in A\times B\times C$. It surely suffices to show that a.e. all $(a,b,c)$ will enter arbitary sets in $\sigma(\mathcal{F}^3)$, but I am not sure whether we can do it for only a generating $\pi$-system.

Since $T\times T$ is ergodic, then there is $n: (T^2)^n\in A\times B$ and there is $m: (T^2)^m \in B\times C$. But then we can't conclude that $T^3(a,b,c)$ eventually enters $A\times B\times C$?

Is there anyone who has a further idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The argument I know goes like this: $T\times T$ ergodic implies that $T$ is weakly mixing (because the operator on $L^2(X)$ has no eigenvalues) which implies that $T\times T\times T$ is ergodic. (Have you heard about any of these implications?)

Comment: @Yanko No, but that is because we have never had any exercise about mixing. I'm gonna look at the topic mixing to check if there is such an argument in one of the books we use.

Comment: @Yanko The first implication is an exercise in one of the books, which was never homework. I don't know about the second.

Comment: There's a theorem that the following are equivalent for a system $(X,T)$. 1. $X$ is weakly mixing. 2. $(X\times X,T\times T)$ is ergodic 3. For every ergodic system $(Y,S)$ the system $(Y\times X,S\times T$ is ergodic.

Comment: From 2 you have 1, and then apply 3 with $Y=X\times X$. I don't know any other way to do this.

Comment: @Yanko If these theorems hold, I agree. This was an exam question from 2015, so maybe the setup was different, i.e. other theorems were covered than in 2018. Or are these theorems easy to prove?

Comment: Not so easy. It goes a long way with like $5$ equivalence of weakly mixing. I'll look for a reference 1 minute.

Comment: Here: Look at the book of Manfred Einsiedler and Thomas Ward. "Ergodic Theory with a view towards number theory" page 51 Theorem 2.36. (also look at Corollary 2.38).